# Metrizable space under lexicographic order topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

While doing some exercises about different metrics, I had a doubt about my comprehension of the matter.

Recall that the lexicographic order on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined as follows :
$$
 (a,b) < (c,d) \iff (a<c) \quad \mathrm{or} \quad (a=c \ \mathrm{and} \ b<d)
$$

We put the order topology on the real plane, so the open intervals of the form  $](a,b), (c,d)[$ look like a vertical open interval if $a=c$ or the union of a vertical line over $(a,b)$ with the band of all the points $(x,y)$ such as $a<x<c$ and the vertical line at $x=c$ up to $y=d$. (I don't know if it makes sense, it was just to get the picture in a sentence... but drawing an example on a sheet of paper should also work.)

If I did not make any mistakes, the real plane with such a topology is metrizable (is it true ?).
For the record, I defined $d$ a metric as :
$$
 d( (x,y), (x',y') ) = 
\begin{cases}
\infty \ \mathrm{if} x \neq x' \\
|y'-y| \ \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I'll skip the proof (but if $d$ is not a good candidate, please feel free to correct me on that point) that $d$ is a metric and defines the same topology that we had from the lexicographic order.

Then, the next question was about the existence of a metric on $[0,1]^2$ that gives the same topology as the one from the order defined above. I think I did the usual proof that consists of saying that the square is compact and therefore, if it was metrizable, it would separable which is not the case with the lexicographic order topology (the line passing through the middle $\{(s,1/2)|s\in[0,1]\}$ is discrete and uncountable).

First, is that statement correct ?

Second, what prevent us to use to induced metric on the square ? I couldn't think of a counter example when someone told me that restricting $d$ to the square was enough to get a metric space. But, as it would contradict the "proof" above, one of them is wrong (or something in broken in the math world, which I highly doubt and fear).

Comment: A metric can never give infinity as a value.

Comment: Your metric would induce vertical intervals only (and entire planes if we allowed infinite distance) but would never produce the bands.  I have a metric Tha will produce verical intervals and bands where b=d.  I.e ((a,b)(a,c)) or ((a,b)(c,b)) but I can't seem to replicate ((a,b)(c,d)).  I don't think it can be done.

Comment: $d$ is certainly not a metric as distances have to be real and $\infty$ is not a real. You can patch that up by taking $d'=\arctan d$ if $y'=y$ and $\frac \pi 2$ otherwise.  This still obeys the triangle inequality and has acceptable output.

Comment: Oops... it seems I forgot basic rules while wanting to have a distance at all costs. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\tau$ be the lexicographic order topology on $\Bbb R^2$ and $\tau_s$ the lexicographic order topology on the unit square $S=[0,1]\times[0,1]$. The main thing that you’re missing, I think, is that $\tau_s$ is *not* the topology that $S$ inherits as a subspace of $\langle\Bbb R^2,\tau\rangle$.

In $\langle\Bbb R^2,\tau\rangle$ each vertical $\{x\}\times\Bbb R$ is a clopen set, and in fact the lexicographically ordered plane is homeomorphic to the product $\Bbb R_d\times\Bbb R$, where $\Bbb R_d$ denotes $\Bbb R$ with the discrete topology, and the second factor $\Bbb R$ has the usual topology. Since $\Bbb R_d$ is metrizable with the [discrete metric](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteMetric.html), this is a product of two metrizable spaces and as such is metrizable. One compatible metric is given by

$$d(\langle x_0,y_0\rangle,\langle x_1,y_1\rangle)=\begin{cases}
\min\{|y_0-y_1|,1\},&\text{if }x_0=x_1\\
1,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

In the relative topology induced on $S$ by $\tau$ the sets $\{x\}\times[0,1]$ for $x\in[0,1]$ would be clopen, and the restriction of $d$ to $S\times S$ would be a metric inducing the relative topology.

In $\tau_s$, however, those sets are not clopen: they’re closed, but they’re not open. If $0<a\le 1$, every open $\tau_s$-nbhd of $\langle a,0\rangle$ contains points $\langle x,0\rangle$ with $x<a$, and if $0\le a<1$, every $\tau_s$-open nbhd of $\langle x,1\rangle$ contains points $\langle x,1\rangle$ with $x>a$. Thus, none of the sets $\{x\}\times[0,1]$ with $x\in[0,1]$ is open in $\tau_s$. It’s this difference between $\tau_s$ and the relative topology inherited from $\tau$ that makes $S$ compact in the topology $\tau_s$, as it clearly is not in the relative topology, in which

$$\big\{\{x\}\times[0,1]:x\in[0,1]\big\}$$

is an open cover of $S$ with no finite subcover — indeed, no proper subcover.

In short, you can start with a compatible metric on the $\langle\Bbb R^2,\tau\rangle$ and restrict it to a metric on $S$, and it will generate the subspace topology on $S$, but this isn’t $\tau_s$, the lexicographic order topology on $S$. Once you realize that you’re looking at two different topologies on $S$, the apparent problem disappears.

As an aside, it’s worth noting that the two topologies actually do agree at all points of $S$ except those of the form $\langle x,0\rangle$ with $0<x\le 1$ and those of the form $\langle x,1\rangle$ with $0\le x<1$.

Comment: That's definitely what I missed.

Comment: $d(\langle x_0,y_0\rangle,\langle x_1,y_1\rangle)=\begin{cases} \min\{|y_0-y_1|,1\},&\text{if }x_0=x_1\\ 1,&\text{otherwise}\;. \end{cases}$.               ${}$ What is the reasoning behind this? How did this come in mind?

Comment: @AmanPandey: We want something like the usual metric on each vertical $\{x\}\times\Bbb R$, and we want something like the usual discrete metric between the verticals. Starting with the latter gives the *otherwise* cases, but then we have to make sure that the triangle inequality is satisfied. Bounding the metric by $1$ vertically takes care of that and doesn’t change the topology: you can **always** bound a metric by a constant without changing the topology, since that depends on what happens near points.

Comment: @Brian When will i be become like you? Why it didn't come in my mind?

Comment: @AmanPandey: Experience helps: I first studied topology in 1966, so I’ve been doing this for a *long* time!

Comment: @Brian I am doing masters. I really stuck in munkres topology exercise. It takes too much time to solve exercise. So for me it's impossible to solve all exercise problems. Any advise Professor

Comment: @AmanPandey: Are you talking about problems that are assigned in a course? If so, it’s possible that the instructor is assigning too much: I’ve seen that happen, even with a rather good instructor. It’s also possible that you’re not picking up the material quite fast enough; I really couldn’t judge without actually seeing how the material is being covered and how much you’re being asked to do. If this is course work, do lots of other people seem to be keeping up, or are most people finding that there isn’t enough time?

Answer (score 1):

The unit square is not compact in this metric.  Your example of the line through the middle proves this.  You just picked the wrong part of the antecendent of (metrizable and compact) $\implies$ separable to deny.

Comment: I understand my mistake, thank you. But I don't see much difference between my question and this article on Wikipedia : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order_topology_on_the_unit_square . Maybe I got confused with the terms they use.