# Metrizability of RxR in the dictionary order topology

Tags: general-topology

The question is one in Munkres where we are asked to prove the metrizability of RxR in the dictionary order topology.

My attempts of defining a metric seem to falter at the end. As for example, I have tried the standard bounded metric, usual metric etc...etc., but all of them give us open balls which can't be contained in a basis element of the dictionary order topology of the form (axb, axc), where b<c.

How do i proceed??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Each vertical $\{x\}\times\Bbb R$ is a clopen subset of $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ in this topology, so the space is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R_d\times\Bbb R$, where $\Bbb R_d$ is the real line with the discrete topology, and the second factor has the usual topology. $\Bbb R_d$ and $\Bbb R$ are both metric spaces. The product of two metric spaces is metrizable; do you know how to construct a metric for it from metrics on the factors? If not, or if you get stuck, take a look at the second paragraph of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938870/metrizable-space-under-lexicographic-order-topology/1939254#1939254).

Answer (score 1):

In $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ in the lexicographic order topology a local neighbourhood of $(x,y)$ can always be chosen to be of the form $\{x\} \times \langle a,b \rangle$ where $\langle a,b \rangle$ is some real open interval containing $y$, and this set equals the open interval $\langle (x,a), (x,b)\rangle$ in this order.

So we essentially have a disjoint sum topology of continuum many copies of $\Bbb R$ in the usual topology (a construction that is not treated in Munkres), which we can also see as $D(\Bbb R) \times \Bbb R$, where the first space is the discrete topology on $\Bbb R$.

A metric on it can be defined as follows: first we truncate the metric on $\Bbb R$ by $1$ (which gives an alternative equivalent metric): $d'(x,y) = \min(|x-y|, 1)$, so no points in $\Bbb R$ then lie more than $1$ apart.

Then define

$$d((x,y), (x',y'))=\begin{cases}
d'(y,y') & \text{ if } x=x'\\
2 & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

so that points in different "stalks" $\{x\}\times \Bbb R$ and $\{x'\} \times \Bbb R$ are "very far" from each other and the triangle inequality becomes easy to check. Check that this metric has balls (for radii $< 2$) that are of the right form as described at the beginning. So the metric $d$ induces the correct topology.